# get numpy array from pygame

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to access my Webcam via python. Unfortunately openCV is not working because of the webcam. Pygame.camera works like a charm with this code:

```
from pygame import camera,display

camera.init()
webcam = camera.Camera(camera.list_cameras()[0])
webcam.start()

img = webcam.get_image()

screen = display.set_mode((img.get_width(), img.get_height()))
display.set_caption("cam")

while True:
    screen.blit(img, (0,0))
    display.flip()   
    img = webcam.get_image()
```

My question is now, how can I get a numpy array from the webcam?

Comment: I'm having trouble making the jump from webcam to numpy array - are you trying to have an array of pixels from the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get_image` returns a [`Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html).  According to http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html, you can use `pygame.surfarray.array2d` (or one of the other functions in the `surfarray` module) to convert the Surface to a numpy array.  E.g.

```
    img = webcam.get_image()
    data = pygame.surfarray.array2d(img)
```