# How to get numpy array of RGB colors from pygame.surface

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pygame

I have code:

```
import pygame.camera
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0])
cam.start()
img = cam.get_image()
```

The img variable is

```
<Surface(640x480x24 SW)>
```

I found the [get numpy array from pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19982760/3960850) but still I do not know how to convert it effectively to numpy array of RGB colors.

Comment: Well, if you apply what the linked answer suggests, `pygame.surfarray.array2d(img)`, what do you get? Just an array with size (640, 480)? Can you give an example of 1-2 numbers that appear there?

Comment: @Reti43 Integer numbers appear there. For example for one image the minimum could be 0 and maximum 14737632

Comment: I would recommend to look into `openCV` library for this kind of tasks, it has video grabber and returns 3d arrays by default.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For grabbing 3D image data from [`class pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), use [`.array3d()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.array3d), as also the doc states -

> Copy pixels into a 3d array
>
> array3d(Surface) -> array

Thus, you could do -

```
imgdata = pygame.surfarray.array3d(img)
```

Please note that the resulting `imgdata` might appear with height and width switched. To fix that, swap the first two axes, like so -

```
imgdata = imgdata.swapaxes(0,1)
```